# Codename one push notifications failing

Tags: push-notification, codenameone

We've got a Codename One app which has been live for some time.
We haven't made any changes or additions to the code but since the weekend push notifications sent to the Codename One push server have been failing without any error message returning.
Any idea why this would be the case?

Comment: The push server doesn't return error codes but it does return a JSON response message. Is that empty? If not what does it contain? 
We were able to track down a verification issue and are pushing a hotfix

Comment: Ah thank you. The server response was completely empty. I'll check in a few hours to confirm its fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed now assuming the server response wasn't empty. If as you say it is empty we'll need to reproduce the issue and for that you should contact the support chat with details about your usage so we can reproduce your exact test case.